# Sharing printer on windows server 2008 using net use

Tags: windows

We have a server running Windows Server 2008 and we have a printer Epson LQ 2180.

We need to share this printer with users on two computers (userA and userB).

Commonly, we use Net Use command like

```
Net Use lpt1: /delete
net use lpt1: \\userB\sharedPrinter /Persistent yes
```

But this command does not work. How do we set things up so userB can access the printer?

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest way for users on both computers to access the printer is to install the printer on the server and then share it on the network.

To do that do the following.

1. Install the printer on the server
2. On the server go to Control Panel
3. Go to Devices and Printers
4. Go to the printer properties (either right click and click Properties or double click and click Customize printer)
5. Go to the Sharing tab
6. Check the box that says Share this printer
7. Enter a name for the shared printer (officeprinter)
8. Click Apply
9. Click OK

On each of your computers you will need to connect to the printer. You can create a batch file that will do this. An example of what you would put in the batch file is below.

```
START \\SERVER\officeprinter
```

A better way would be to do this with a Visual Basic Script.

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\SERVER\officeprinter"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter \\SERVER\officeprinter
```

Comment: The problem is, the printer is located on 2nd floor of my building, then the server on 4th floor. How about that ?

Comment: If they are connected to the same network and they can communicate with each other that is not a problem.